# Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property on null

Tags: php

I was migrating a code from v7.4 to 8.0 and encountered this error on one of my page but was unable to solve it i know in php v8.0 this error will be encountered as written in migrating docs

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "allow_basic" on null in /homepages/5/d742909641/htdocs/payroll/Payroll/demo/demo/allowance_setup.php:77 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /homepages/5/d742909641/htdocs/payroll/Payroll/demo/demo/allowance_setup.php on line 77
```

Code:

```
        $o1->allow_basic = implode("|", $allow_basic);
        $o10->allow_basic = implode("|", $allow_basic);
```

Comment: The error is telling you that either `$o1` or `$o10` (or both) is `null`.

Comment: @David how to solve that?

Comment: Either assign a value to it or don't try to de-reference it when it's `null`.

Comment: @David can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, for example, if you want to assign an object to a variable (for the sake of example let's call the class `myClass`), you would do this: `$o1 = new myClass;`  To learn about variables and objects in PHP you are encouraged to start with some introductory PHP tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear:

> Attempt to assign property "allow_basic" on null

`$o1` is null before you call `$o1->allow_basic`, which results in the error.

You have to define `$o1` as a stdClass before using it:

```
$o1 = new stdClass();
$o1->allow_basic = 'foo';
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/LApiD)

See the PHP documentation about `stdClass`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stdclass.php#stdclass.properties-example